# Eclipse Android Perspectives

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hey these perspectives have gone (no longer available). How do I get them back? thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade your eclipse and then this happened?

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you have the correct versions of Eclipse, the ADT plugin, and the SDK installed:

Window > Open Perspective > Other > DDMS

The main android coding perspective is just the Java Perspective.

Answer (score 3):

The **standard** Android perspective in Eclipse Juno (Version: 4.2.2) is at:

```
Window > Open Perspective > Java
```

Answer (score -1):

More than a version of Eclipse may be conflicting. Just Change the workspace folder or choose a new one.